# 'OR' condition in fetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015, fetchxml

I have to achieve 'OR' condition using fetchXML in CRM 2015 between two different entities. I need to make the condition contact.region = 'region1" or firm.region = "region1". I realize I have to use `<link-entity>` tag, but I am not sure how to implement 'OR' condition.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. To get such kind of query you will have to make calls with such filters 2 times and then merge resultsets.